# Grouping the intake and identify number of students who did not enroll for other classes among the student in the intake

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax, powerquery

```
intake            class       student_id
Sep 2022 - Eng    English     100
Sep 2022 - Eng    English     101
Nov 2022 - Sc     Science     100
Jan 2023 - Bio    Biology     101
Nov 2022 - Sc     Science     102
Sep 2022 - Eng    English     102
Jan 2023 - Bio    Biology     102
Jan 2023 - Bio    Biology     103
Jan 2023 - Bio    Biology     105
Feb 2023 - Eng    English     104
Feb 2023 - Eng    English     103
```

Hello everyone,

I have a table as shown above. Each row in the table represent the student who is going to attend the classes. For example by looking at the Sep 2022 English class, I know that students with ID `100,101,102` are going to attend the class, and student `100,102` are going to attend Nov 2022 Science class, etc...

What I want to do is to transform the table into another format where it tells how many students did not attend or are not going to attend other classes among the students that are attending the class right now. The table below is the expected output:

[image]

I will show how to get the value in the table that are shown in the screenshot:

### For example

When student `100,101,102` are attending the Sep 2022 English class, among three of them:

- None of them did not attend or not going to attend English class (as they are
  attending the English class right now);
- One of them did not attend or not going to attend science class (student
  `101`) since only student `100,102` are in the list of science class;
- One of them did not attend or not going to attend biology class
  (student `100`) since only student `101,102` are in the list
  to attend biology class and student `100` is not in the list.

Hence, for Sep 2022 - Eng intake:

- no_english = 0
- no_science = 1
- no_biology = 1

### Giving another example

When student `101,102,103,105` are attending the Jan 2023 Biology class, among 4 of them:

- One of them did not attend or not going to attend English class (student `105`) since student `101,102` attended Sep 2022 English class and student `103` going to attend Feb 2023 English class;
- three of them did not attend or not going to attend science class (student
  `101,103,105`) since only student `102` are in the list of science class;
- None of them did not attend or not going to attend biology class since all of them are attending Biology class right now.

Hence, for Jan 2023 - Bio intake:

- no_english = 1
- no_science = 3
- no_biology = 0

I have been struggled to transform the data into the desired format like what I show in the screenshot. In fact, I'm not sure whether it is possible to do it or not using powerquery or DAX. Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: This reads like a fairytale riddle :D

Comment: Your double negations ("none of them did not attend") make things unnecessarily confusing, but funny to read.

Comment: sorry, is it not clear ? haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Add 3 measures to a table as follows:

```
no_science = 

VAR ids = VALUES('Table'[student_id])
VAR ids_sci = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES( 'Table'[student_id]), REMOVEFILTERS('Table'), 'Table'[class] = "Science")


RETURN COUNTX( EXCEPT(ids, ids_sci), 'Table'[student_id])+0


no_english = 

VAR ids = VALUES('Table'[student_id])
VAR ids_eng = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES( 'Table'[student_id]), REMOVEFILTERS('Table'), 'Table'[class] = "English")


RETURN COUNTX( EXCEPT(ids, ids_eng), 'Table'[student_id])+0



no_biology = 

VAR ids = VALUES('Table'[student_id])
VAR ids_bio = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES( 'Table'[student_id]), REMOVEFILTERS('Table'), 'Table'[class] = "Biology")


RETURN COUNTX( EXCEPT(ids, ids_bio), 'Table'[student_id])+0
```

Comment: Thanks David for your input, when I was using the measure in sample dataset that I posted in my question, everything works well but not sure why when I applied the measure on the real dataset, there is an issue occur in `RETURN COUNTX( EXCEPT(ids, ids_bio), 'Table'[student_id])+0`. The error mentioned that `A single value for column 'student_id' in table 'Table' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.` Any idea how should I fix this?

Comment: Not sure whether there is any function that I can use to wrap the `student_id` and yet without affecting the result?

Comment: Try this but not sure it is accurate without access to your proper dataset.

Comment: RETURN COUNTX( EXCEPT(ids, ids_bio), max( 'Table'[student_id]))+0

Answer (score 2):

For fun, an M version

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"intake", "student_id"}, {{"data", each _, type table }}),
AllCombos =Table.ExpandListColumn( Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "class", each List.Distinct(Source[class])), "class"),

T1 = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.AddColumn(Table.FromList(List.Distinct(Source[class]), null,{"class"} ),"student_id", each List.Distinct(Source[student_id])), "student_id"),
#"Merged Queries0" = Table.NestedJoin(T1, {"class", "student_id"}, Source, {"class", "student_id"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
StudentNo = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries0", "No", each if Table.RowCount([Table1])=0 then 1 else 0),

#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(AllCombos, {"student_id", "class"}, StudentNo, {"student_id", "class"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"No"}, {"No"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Table2",{"student_id", "data"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[class]), "class", "No", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Thanks horseyride, I tried your method, but until last step `Pivot Column`, the data keep loading. I guess it is because my dataset is too big to perform this haha